# <nav> element won't show with heading

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

I am making a webpage that requires a navigation menu at the top, with a header for every section using the

```
<h1>
```

element.  The problem is, when I write the heading, the navigation disappears.  Using

```
tabTitle {
margin-top: 500px;
}
```

in CSS just makes the heading lower on the page, and the navigation is still missing.  How can I fix this?

Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta-charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="top-menubar">
            <nav>
                <a href=tab1.html">1</a> |
                <a href="tab2.html">2</a> |
                <a href="tab3.html">3</a> |
                <a href="tab4.html">4</a> |
                <a href="tab5.html">5</a> 
            </nav>
<h1 id="tabTitle">Tab 5</h1>
    </body>
</html>
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
 #top-menubar {
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
float: none;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
z-index: 1;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
text-transform: uppercase;
margin-top: 25px;
color: black;
}
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  opacity: 100% !important;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transform: scale(2, 3) !important;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #b5b5b5;
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#tabTitle {
margin-top: 500px;
}
</style>
```

ANSWER: Apparently, this can be fixed by applying the

```
position: absolute;
```

tag to the heading.

Comment: try zoom out `ctrl + -`  in browser and check may be it goes out of screen due to `transform` property.

Comment: That's a really great example on why you shouldn't use `position: absolute` It gives you quick results but as soon as you add something it breaks. Try building the layout with modern solutions, you won't need position absolute anywhere for your problem, I'm sure.

Comment: First, fix `<a href=tab1.html">1</a> |` - seems you forgot to open the double-quotes:  `<a href="tab1.html">1</a> |`.

Answer (score 0):

Guess this might help you and there is no need of defining position to absolute

```css
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

#top-menubar {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  float: none;
  /*
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
*/
  z-index: 1;
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* margin-top: 25px; */
  color: black;
  /**/
  padding: 25px 0 0 0;
  background: darkcyan;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  opacity: 100% !important;
  /* added */
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 15px;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transform: scale(2, 3) !important;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #b5b5b5;
  background-color: #b5b5b5;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#tabTitle {
  /* margin-top: 500px; */
  /* added */
  margin: 80px 210px;
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="top-menubar">
    <nav>
      <a href="tab1.html">1</a> |
      <a href="tab2.html">2</a> |
      <a href="tab3.html">3</a> |
      <a href="tab4.html">4</a> |
      <a href="tab5.html">5</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <h1 id="tabTitle">Tab 5</h1>
</body>
```